# The best student

Tags: probability, integration

Suppose two students called **A** and **B**. Student A has answered $k_A$ questions correctly out of $n_A$ questions. Student B has answered $k_B$ correctly out of $n_B$ questions. **Who is the best student** assuming each student has a constant likelihood (drawn from uniform distribution) of answering correctly to a given question.

Is this same as asking which one of following integrals is larger?

$$\int_{0}^{1} p_A^{k_A}(1-p_A)^{n_A-k_A}\int_{p_A}^{1}p_B^{k_B}(1-p_B)^{n_B-k_B}dp_Bdp_A$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} p_A^{k_A}(1-p_A)^{n_A-k_A}\int_{0}^{p_A}p_B^{k_B}(1-p_B)^{n_B-k_B}dp_Bdp_A$$

Integrating these integrals are beyond my capabilities so help is appreciated.

Comment: Obviously there is not enough information here to determine who is the best student (because, for example, one student might have gotten very lucky).  So you need to figure out what you really want to ask, and then the answer will depend on what the question is.

Comment: You are right that it's impossible to tell which one of the students is really the best one. The question is who is the "best" student based on given information (ie. which student has higher likelihood of being the best).

Comment: I would compare the probabilities of a binomial distribution. For student A: $P(X=k_a)={n_a \choose k_a} \cdot p_a^{k_a}\cdot (1-p_a)^{n_a-k_a}$. Student B have a similar pdf.

Comment: But actually I do not how to continue.

Comment: That is similar to what I am thinking. Correct me if I am wrong for student A we have:

Comment: $P(p_a = p)=\frac{(n_a+1)!}{k_a!(n_a-k_a)!}p^{k_a}(1-p)^{n_a-k_a}$

Comment: And from that we get $P(p_a < p_b) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{p}^{1} P(p_a = p , p_b = q)dq dp =  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{p}^{1} P(p_a = p)P(p_b = q)dq dp$   $= \int_{0}^{1} P(p_a = p)\int_{p}^{1} P(p_b = q)dq dp$